# Can't drag image onto scene

Tags: unity

First time trying Unity and I'm having trouble with importing assets.

border_horizontal.png is fine, but I can't drag border_vertical.png onto my scene. It also doesn't have an arrow next to it in the asset menu. What is going on here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: screenshot of the inspector while this image is selected will help me determine what is wrong.

Comment: You can use an animated gif recording tool such as GifCam and ScreenToGif to help capture what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well ok try this. Delete this sprite, Restart unity, reimport it and see if it works.

Comment: Tried that a few times. it seems to be just this particular image, any others are fine. It's from this tutorial : http://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-snake-game